# Adding dependencies for sending mail in java

Tags: java, email, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail

I am trying to write add sending an email to an application I have written in java, I found a good guide. http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

But how do I add the `javaee.jar` and `mail.jar` dependencies?

I added the dependencies but I get

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host:
>   smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;   nested exception is:
>     java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87:
>   create    at sendMail.main(sendMail.java:47) Caused by:
>   javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host:
>   smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;   nested exception is:
>     java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87:
>   create    at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
>     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)     at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)  at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)  at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)    at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)     at
>   sendMail.main(sendMail.java:42) Caused by: java.net.SocketException:
>   Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create    at
>   java.net.Socket.createImpl(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:321)
>     at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:237)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
>     ... 7 more "

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: You add the jars to your build path with your IDE.Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Yes I'm using eclipse I don't know where to find the javaee.jar though? I believe I added the mail one

Comment: Are u under a proxy server?

Comment: no (Comment too short)

Comment: Have you tried the SSL version encryption version or instead of smtp.gmail.com try smtp.googlemail,com

Answer (score 0):

In the Package Explorer view, right-click the project that you want to add a dependency to.

Click Build Path > Configure Build Path.
Click the Libraries tab.
Complete one of the following tasks:

Click Add JARS if the .jar file is in the current workspace.
Click Add External JARS if the .jar file is not in the current workspace.

Select the .jar file that you want.
Click OK.

Comment: Yes i've clicked add external jar's but I have no idea where to find the jars

Comment: Have you downloaded them to?If you haven't you've got to download the API version you want.Are you on Java EE 5 or 6?

For Java EE 5: http://download.java.net/maven/1/javaee/jars/javaee-api-5.jar
For Java EE 6: http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/javaee-api/6.0/javaee-api-6.0.jar

For mail.jar: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/1.4

Comment: im on 6, maybe i need a newer mail version too, where can I find that one?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a firewall or anti-virus product that's preventing you from connecting.

See the JavaMail FAQ for [tips for debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

Answer (score 0):

When sending mail through the SMTP protocol, the port should be set to 465. Change your port to 465 and then try again.